# Phonegap iOS DB Query

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, cordova, lawnchair

I am using Phonegap 1.3.0, and want to develop an app which uses local storage. Some googling brought me to sqlite, but i have had no success in implementing it in my app.

https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

I tried this link but i am really not sure what this lawnchair.js is all about.
Sqlite is my priority but I can try other options too. I also tried window.opendatabase() but it doesnt work in my app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lawnchair is a wrapper over many storage methods. There is localstorage, sqlite, blackberry specific, and others.
There are many adapters in lawnchair to store stuff. 
 http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/adapters/ 
The way lawnchair works is, if an adapter is specified, it will use that, or if no adapter is specified and if the code of all adapters is appended to lawnchair.js file, then lawnchair checks which one to use in the order of they are appended and picks the first one it finds suitable. 

What makes lawnchair easy to use is that we don't have to deal with sql syntaxs (assuming u want to use sqlite adapter.)  You just store and retrieve your data in JSON by

```
table.save(key:"obj", name:{a:"aaaa", b:"bbbb"})

table.get(key:"obj", function(ob){
  //callback
})
```

and internally lawnchair will save data in sqlite. 
You can use any adapter, but all u have to use is the above syntax. easy. lawnchair is a powerful wrapper over many storage options. check it out

Comment: // Open local DB connection
var lawnchair = new Lawnchair({table:'mytable', adaptor:PGSQLitePlugin.lawnchair_adapter}, function(){
// Lawnchair setup! 
});

// Saving to the database
lawnchair.save({key:'my_data_key', lastSync: currentTime, dataList: someData});
lawnchair.get('my_data_key',function(me){
logToConsole(me);
});
I have tried this but it doesnt do anything

Comment: i have implemented it through your example. It was just a value mishap. Anyways, can you tell me where does the database get stored?

Comment: so does it work now? you want to use the webkit-sqlite plugin, right?

Comment: it is working now through the lawnchair.js . And i am using the same adapter as given in the link from github davibe i.e. PGSQLitePlugin.lawnchair_adapter

Comment: ohk. to make sure its using this adapter only and not its own, try executing your code in chrome and run test sql queries on its console to get ans save data

Comment: I tried running this piece of code from the link given above but it doesn't do anything.    var db;
  db = new PGSQLitePlugin("test_native.sqlite3");
  db.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
  db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
   return tx.executeSql(["INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", "test", 100], function(res) {
   logToConsole("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
   logToConsole("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
   r

Comment: edit the question or ask as a separate question. impossible to read code in comments :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8071/discussion-between-user790514-and-ghostcoder)